# DDD Dispatch event of related entities

Tags: .net, .net-core, event-handling, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern

To disable a profile associated to a user we usually

- Load the user from the db
- Call the `User.RemoveProfile(ProfileId)` method.
- Within this method, we will find the specified profile within a list and then we call the `Profile.Disable()` method
- Within the `Profile.Disable()` we raise the `ProfileDisabled` event.
- We perfect user + related entities (in that case profiles) to DB.

Currently events are stored inside each entity. When we persist users in the db we go through events under user and NOT under all associated profiles. As a result, we don't dispatch profile events and they get lost.

For your reference this is the code we use to dispatch event:

```
public abstract class Repository
{
    private readonly IMediator _mediator;

    protected Repository(IMediator mediator) => _mediator = mediator;

    // Future: Use EventStore for audit
    /* Bug: Disable profile raises an event stored at the profile level. When user gets updated only
       user events are dispatched. Profile events are lost... */
    protected async Task DispatchEventsAsync(Entity entity, CancellationToken token)
    {
        Ensure.Any.IsNotNull(entity, nameof(entity));
        await Task.WhenAll(entity.Events.Select(e => _mediator.Publish(e, token)));
        entity.SuppressEvents();
    }
}
```

Where `Entity` is:

```
public interface IEntity { }

public abstract class Entity : IEntity
{
    private readonly List<DomainEvent> _events = new List<DomainEvent>();

    [NotMapped]
    public IReadOnlyList<DomainEvent> Events => _events.AsReadOnly();
    public bool HasEvents => _events.Any();

    protected void Emit(DomainEvent eventItem)
    {
        if (eventItem != null && !_events.Contains(eventItem))
            _events.Add(eventItem);
    }

    public void SuppressEvents() => _events.Clear();
}
```

As you can see Entity does NOT know about related entities. This there is no way to access related events.

How would handle this case? Does this mean only Aggregate Root can raise events?

Thx
Seb

Comment: I'm not a C# expert but couldn't you just overload the method `public IReadOnlyList<DomainEvent> Events => _events.AsReadOnly();`? in the `User` class it should return its own events and the events from nested profiles

Comment: The idea typically is that all interaction should take place through the AR so perhaps that is the way to go.  Also, if you favour Value Objects over Entities within your AR the AR would have to take care of the event(s) anyway.  I'd go with that plan :)

Comment: Indeed. Good solution. The other alternative we found consist in relying on EF Core to list all added/modified/deleted entities, loop through them and dispatch the associated events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have an aggregate with two entities: User and Profile. And User is the AR.

Events are raised when you perform an operation on the aggregate, so you should store them with the AR.

In your case the operation is "user.removeProfile(profileId)", so the AR should raise the event "ProfileRemovedFromUser" or something like that.

NOTE: Your UL is ambiguous, as you use the words remove and disable for the same thing. You should use just one word.